# Embend Fragment inside CastPresentation

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, chromecast

I want to use [Cast Presentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastPresentation?hl=pt-pt) to send my fragment (that contains a map actually) to the screen and see it working like on my phone...

How can I do it?

Comment: any solution for that?

Comment: @gmartinsnull nope

Answer (score 1):

Use the Google Cast Remote Display API: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote

You should be able to add any view that you would normally add to an Activity.

Comment: Yeah but the presentation dont have onPause, onDestroy and others, when I add the map is showed but just load one part of the map and stop refreshing it. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView

Comment: You can dynamicaly create MapView with liteMode and than you only need onCreate(): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite